# Is it possible to disable username change with Clerk?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, clerk

For now, I don't want users being able to change their usernames on my app, as that would complicate some things on the backend. Ideally, I would like to be able to do it both on the server side (Clerk's dashboard) and also on the `<UserButton/>`'s modal.

I haven't been able to find any options related to this on `<UserButton/>`. Do they even exist? Here is the [`clerk.ts`](https://github.com/clerk/javascript/blob/d815a93666e661d08ced91dc333755d0f80d51a5/packages/types/src/clerk.ts#L796-L836) related file.

Is it also possible to do something like it but to the "delete account" action?

[image: Clerk Username Change]

Comment: If we can find an answer in the Discord I will add it here too :)

Comment: With respect to the "delete account" action, it's worth pointing out that it is possible to forbid it from Clerk's dashboard at least.